# How do I allow a specific AD user to add computers to the domain, limited to a specific OU?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I'm in the process of putting together a puppet recipe which will install Likewise Open on Linux machines and join them to a specific OU in our AD structure.

Since the only practical way to do this involves storing the credentials of an AD user in plain text in the puppet manifest, I want to create a dedicated AD user which only has rights to join computers to a specific OU.

I recall doing something like this years ago but I'm a little rusty on the details.

I have already created an AD user and made sure it is in the Domain Guests group rather than Domain Users, but I'm not sure of the exact details I should use when I delegate rights to this user on the OU.

Can someone tell me the specific options and rights I need to use in the Delegate Control wizard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating a group named something like *Account Management Computers*, to which you would add this account as a member. This way you can always modify the group members to update delegation without changing the ACL.

- Start the Delegate Control wizard on the OU/CN you want to modify.
- Select the group/user. Choose *"Create a custom task to delegate"*.
- Select *"Only the following objects in the folder"*.
- Tick: *"Computer objects"* and *"Create selected objects in this folder"*.
- On the next page, tick *"Create all child objects"*.